# Calculate total of rows in ng-repeat with other controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I got rows where a total will be calculated.

In my ng-repeat I have a controller `RowCtrl` where I calculate the total.

```
app.controller('RowCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.unit_price = 0;
   $scope.quantity = 0;

   $scope.$watchCollection('[row.unit_price, row.quantity]', function () {
      $scope.row.total = $scope.row.unit_price * $scope.row.quantity;
   });
});
```

How can I calculate the total of all the rows?

In the fiddlr I have a demo of the rows where the total of a row is already calculated.

Fiddlr: http://jsfiddle.net/9t9em/1/

Answer (score 3):

you don't need RowCtrl

http://jsfiddle.net/9t9em/5/

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.rows = [{
        unit_price: 1,
        quantity: 0
    }, {
        unit_price: 2,
        quantity: 0
    }, {
        unit_price: 3,
        quantity: 0
    }];
    $scope.$watch('rows', function () {
        $scope.total = 0
        angular.forEach($scope.rows, function(row){
            $scope.total += row.unit_price * row.quantity
        })
    }, true)
});
```

Comment: How can I implement this, when I retrieve $scope.rows from a $http request?

Comment: If you do $http request then in success assign your response to `$scope.rows` the DOM will be generated as usually

Comment: And the $scope.$watch as well?

Comment: My array is like this:
$scope.estimate > subs > rows. How am I suppose to $watch the rows?
Foreach till I'm at the rows collection?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - just use `objectEquality` parameter(to check child elements for changes):

```
$scope.$watch('rows', function () {...}, true);
```

But better - just do it in your template:

```
{{unit_price * quantity | number:2}}
```

This would be more efficient, and less error-prone.

---

Why It should be in view?

Because it is view logic.. I mean: it is about: how to display certain row.

Is it ok to put this logic to view?

In case of simple multiplication(as in this case) - I think, it is OK. But in more complicated cases it would be better to add special filter for this.

Why it would be mach more efficient than deep watch and totals recalculation on it?

Because this recalculations would be called on every possible change in every row, and will recalculate all totals (not olny required one). But if you do this in view - angular would be watching only for certain properties in certain rows, so it will recalculate total only when this would be required.

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't like to put too much logic in templates as IMHO in Angularjs MVC the data drives the view and view should be simply used to display not calculate it ;)

Comment: @maurycy added explanation, why it should be in view, and how to not bloat view with logic

Comment: One question: how would this `{{unit_price * quantity | number:2}}` calculate the form total? ;)

Comment: @maurycy in original question total means total price for certain row.. to calculate total in whole form you will need deep watch...

Comment: the original question remain same from beginning `How can I calculate the total of all the rows?` which I understood as total of all rows not a total of each row