# How to calculate sum of all comments in a post?

Tags: angularjs, sum, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have read on various examples on SO, namely:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731145/calculating-sum-of-repeated-elements-in-angularjs-ng-repeat)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186243/calculate-average-from-list-of-values-in-json)

[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24323446/calculate-total-of-rows-in-ng-repeat-with-other-controller)

In my case, its simpler, I just need sum instead of average or sumproduct.

My code is `ng-repeat = comment in comments` and in html, `{{comment.sumComment()}}`.

Then i tried 3 variations which I did something wrong in all, since none work.
Could someone help me on this?

**Method 1**

```
$scope.sumComment = function(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0, i < $scope.comments.length; i++){
        var comment = $scope.comments[i];
        sum += comment;
    }
    return sum;
};
```

**Method 2**

```
*$scope.$watch('comment', function () {
    $scope.total = 0
    angular.forEach($scope.comment, function(comment){
        $scope.total += comment
            })
        },  true)
```

**Method 3** - replaced key with postId and data with comment, in a new filter.js file.

```
.filter('sumComment', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' && typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + data[i][key];
        }
        return sum;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

Your `html` snippet is wrong. You call the `sumComment()` of the object `comment` and not the desired `$scope` method. Try:

```
{{sumComment()}}
```

```
$scope.sumComment = function(){
    return comments.length();
};
```

**METHOD 2**
Here you are adding objects to a number. Try the following

```
{{total}}
```

```
$scope.$watch('comments', function () {
    $scope.total = $scope.comments.length;
    });
```

**METHOD 3**

Here is a working snippet for method 3:

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.filter('sumComments', function () {
    return function (comments) {
        if (typeof (comments) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }
        
        return comments.length;
    }
})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.comments = [1,2,3];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyModule">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      Total: {{comments| sumComments}}
    </div>
</body>
```

**METHOD 4**

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.comments = [1,2,3,4];
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyModule">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Total: {{comments.length}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: for method 3, what should be replaced for data and key?

Comment: I have updated my code. The first parameter is the element, which is in your case `comments`. Additional parameter of the filter function are arguments for the filter. For example `{{input | filter:myString}}` here is `input` the first parameter and `myString` the second parameter of the filter function. [Here is an explanation](http://toddmotto.com/everything-about-custom-filters-in-angular-js/)

Comment: Thanks for your great help! I havent managed to get it working...so far method 2 seems to be the closest. At least theres a number appearing. I cant use [] cos the original tutorial saves the comments and id in a firebase backend.